# Hide category in the WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've been trying to hide a specific category from SHOP page. I found this code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'CATEGORY TO HIDE' ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )));

    remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

I've pasted this code in my theme function.php file but I'm not achieving the result...

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Please fix the title of your post. All caps is just plain rude....

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a bit late, but had this problem myself and solved it with the following function:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

  $new_terms = array();

  // if a product category and on the shop page
  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( '**CATEGORY-HERE**' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }

    }

    $terms = $new_terms;
  }

  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted the code. added category slug. removed `is_shop()`. but the category name is still being displayed on single product page of woocommerce.

Comment: why did you remove is_shop() ?

Comment: I just don't want it to appear anywhere on the website. Not only at shop pages. That's why.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same issue and tried the above code with is_page() instead of is_shop() with still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet it works fine for me:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'your category slug' ), // Don't display products in the knives category on the shop page
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

I'm wondering how can I achieve the same for the products excluded within the category to be searchable via product search, while using the snippet those products gets totally hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to hide a category from everything except the admin backend:

In `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'hide_category', 10, 1 );
function hide_category( $terms ) {
  $new_terms = array();
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( $term->slug !== 'secret_category' ) {
      $new_terms[] = $term;
    } else if ( $term->taxonomy !== 'product_cat' || is_admin() ) {
      $new_terms[] = $term;
    }
  }
  return $new_terms;
}
```

If you want to only hide it from the shop, add `|| !is_shop()` to the `else if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide some categories in your theme you can just pass `exclude` argument in the `wp_list_categories` function:

```
wp_list_categories( array(
'taxonomy'              =>  'product_cat',
'hide_empty'            =>  1,
'use_desc_for_title'    =>  0,
'title_li'              =>  '&nbsp;',
'show_count'            =>  0,
'exclude'               =>  '63'    // <-- Hidden) );
```