# Hiding a specific category in WooCommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide every product in my shop that is in the "Testing" category.  I have tried the following 3 sets of code that I have found on these forums, to no avail.

```
function ts_get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
$new_terms = array();
// if it is a product category and on the shop page
if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() &&is_shop() || is_product_category()) {
foreach( $terms as $key => $term ) {
if ( !in_array( $term->slug, array( 'testing' ) ) ) { //pass the slug name here
$new_terms[] = $term;
}}
$terms = $new_terms;
}
return $terms;
}
```

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'testing' ), // Don't display products in the testing category on the shop page
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

```
function hide_category( $terms ) {
  $new_terms = array();
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( $term->slug !== 'testing' ) {
      $new_terms[] = $term;
    } else if ( $term->taxonomy !== 'product_cat' || is_admin() ) {
      $new_terms[] = $term;
    }
  }
  return $new_terms;
}
```

The products still show up in my shop.  Any suggestions?  And to make it a bit more complicated, I would love it if the products could have other categories, but still not show up if 'testing' is one of the categories.  I currently have my product only in the 'testing' category to try and make this work, but would like it to be in multiple categories and still not show.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide category in the WooCommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366764/hide-category-in-the-woocommerce-shop-page)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, when it comes to hide the category. Please use your keywords and slugs in below mentioned code snippets. let me know if you have any issue.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'hide_specific_category_in_shop');

function hide_specific_category_in_shop($query) {
    // Check if this is the main query and it's the shop page
    if (is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_shop()) {
        return;
    }

    // Exclude specific category from the shop
    $query->set('tax_query', array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'category-slug-to-hide',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Nope, still same results. Item shows up. I've checked the product category slug, tried using the page ID instead of is_shop.

Comment: What do you insert in taxonomy, fields and terms can you tell me?

Comment: 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'testing',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',

Comment: Okay. It seems right. Then the issue is somewhere else.